# Firebase Authentication Failed [Access not configured]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I've been using firebase for months but this problem never occured on my other projects. I wrote same code for authentication with email/password when I want to sign in use regular  signInWithEmailAndPassword() method it give me this error:

```
 com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Access Not Configured.
 Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project <Project-id> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https ]
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbix.zzcb(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf.zzcc(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbja$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

I enabled it email/password sign-in method in firebase console I also re generate sha-1 sign and overwrite existing google-service.json But none of them solve my problem.

Edit for code example:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
           .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivtity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                       Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                   }
               }
           });
```

Comment: Please add same code.

Comment: I edited my question @AlexMamo

Comment: Same problem here, working with Firebase in other projects, but suddenly...

Comment: I figured out problem if you use firebase build in integration in android studio you get this error but if you did in firebase console and manually add sha-1 to Project then download google-service.json it solve my problem.